# Address auto-complete API

Tags: c#, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api, mvvmcross

Is there a web API for addresses auto-complete?

I'm developing a cross-platform mobile application using `Xamarin` + `MvvmCross` frameworks solution, and I need a way to provide the user with address auto-completion.

The final goal is to enable the user to start typing an address and see address suggestions on the view.

Preferring the use of Google Maps, does anyone knows of a way in which I can consume address auto-complete from a shared-code project written in C#? (No JavaScript answers please).

Other ideas are appreciated as well.

Comment: Hi Liel! I am looking for exactly the same! Do you have some code to share?

Comment: For autocomplete implementation by using google place api you check out this http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/09/xamarinios-location-autocomplete-by.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend OpenStreetMap's Nominatim API: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim
Or if you prefer Google Maps, take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete. You just need an XML or a JSON parser, to make it work.

Comment: Great! I knew there was something hiding out there. Can you describe why do you recommend the OpenStreetMap option?

Comment: Basically because it's free. As far as I know Google Maps Places API is free for 2.500 request / 24 hours (or 100.000 request / 24 hour, if you provide your credit card in Google Console).